# How to add GitHub link in bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

I have a GitHub link and I want to use it as a reference. How can I put it in a `.bib` file and then cite it? I am using `bibtex`.

An example GitHub link I want to reference: https://github.com/LLNL/zfp

Comment: Some more context might help, you're using bibtex or biblatex/biber? What is the github link to you: a webpage? a piece of software? a data source? or some other resource?

Comment: This is the link https://github.com/LLNL/zfp and I use bibtex

Comment: Please use the correct tags in the future, there is a big difference between `bibtex` and `biblatex`. I had already wrote my answer so posting it anyway as perhaps it will be useful to `biblatex` users in the future

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using `biblatex` or `bibtex` so will post this anyway. Here is a solution using `biblatex` that I use in my reports:

[image]

I use the `@Online` bib field and do not typically include the accessed date but it is always nice to have it just in case you do need it. The URL is hyperlinked from `hyperref`, the font of the URL has been made the same as the surrounding text by `xurl` and `\urlstyle{same}` and the leading `https://` etc has been stripped using a `\DeclareSourceMap`. If this isn't helpful to you then hopefully it helps someone in the future.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Online{duckgogit,
  accessed = {2023-06-23},
  author   = {{DuckDuckGo}},
  title    = {DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials browser extension for Firefox, Chrome},
  url      = {https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckgo-privacy-extension/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

% Properly formats the URLS and allows breaks, \urlstyle{same} makes the font
% the same as surrounding text
\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% To get rid of https:// in urls
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url, final=true]
      \step[fieldset=verba, origfieldval, final=true]
      \step[fieldsource=verba, match=\regexp{\A(ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}

% to modify the URL format and remove URL:
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{verba}}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] \cite{duckgogit} \lipsum[1][1].

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```